# Create a catalog without ArrayList String

Tags: java

My assignment requires me to create a product catalog. Apparently, I am not allowed to use an ArrayList String anywhere. I have to use only A String specifically in the "Build catalog" method that will return a random price for the product the user enters if it is part of the catalog. Anyone know how to create this catalog without using an Array List but instead using only a string? My code works below but not with only a String... thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    bannerPrinter();
    ArrayList<String> products = productsBuilder();
    Boolean productExists = getOrder(products);
    if (productExists) {
        double price = getPrice();
        double tax = getTax(price * .10);
        double saleTotal = tax + price;
        printTotal(saleTotal);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Product not found.");
    }

}

public static void bannerPrinter() {

    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("====== Welcome to my eCommerce app! ======");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println();

}

public static ArrayList<String> productsBuilder() {
    ArrayList<String> productsCatalog = new ArrayList<String>();
    productsCatalog.add("Headphones");
    productsCatalog.add("Glue Stick");
    productsCatalog.add("Calculator");

    return productsCatalog;
}

public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userProduct = "";
    System.out.print("Please enter a product name: ");
    userProduct = in.nextLine();
    boolean productName = products.contains(userProduct);

    if (productName) {
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
    return productName;
}

public static double getPrice() {
    double price = 0.0;
    price = (Math.random()) * 10;

    return price;
}

public static double getTax(double price) {
    double tax = 0.0;
    tax = price * .10;
    return tax;
}

public static double getTotal(double price, double tax) {
    double saleTotal = 0.0;
    saleTotal = price + tax;
    return saleTotal;
}

public static void printTotal(double saleTotal) {
    System.out.printf("Your sale total is $%.2f", saleTotal);
    System.out.println("");

}
```

}

Comment: Just use a regular list than. Alternatively, you could use a `set` or `hashmap`, but I wouldn't suggest a map.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example of what you mean by a regular list?

Comment: Can not using `ArrayList` then you can using an `String[]` array. Did you try?

Comment: If i understood correctly you want to build the catalog without a `List` only a `String` ? If so, you can store all your product names in a single `String` separated by a special character, that you then parse to retrieve them. Like so `String products = "Headphones;Glue Stick;Calculator";`

Comment: sorry, not a regular list :P I try a linked on instead: `LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();` Alternatively, you could use a `StringBuilder`, and at every append statement just throw a semi colon at the end. Then, turn it  into an array: `String[] array = stringbuilder.toString().split(";")`

Comment: @Isac exactly! Thanks so much!